# imdbpy Getting activity of actors/actresses from a list

Tags: python, imdbpy

I was wondering if someone could help me get a list of all the actor's actress's filmography from a single show?

```
full_cast = ia.get_movie('0203259', 'full credits')
full_cast = full_cast['cast']
full_cast
```

I can get the filmography of one person using:

```
ice_t=i.get_person('0001384')
for job in ice_t['filmography'].keys():
    print('# Job:', job)
    for movie in ice_t['filmography'][job]:
        print('\t t%s %s (role: %s)' % (movie.movieID, movie['title'], movie.currentRole))
```

but I don't know how to apply the function above to full_cast. Can someone help?

Comment: I don't know what `full_cast` returns, but if it returns something that includes the person ID number, it's clearly just `for person in full_cast:` / `per = i.get_person(person.id)` or whatever.  Right?  Just a nested loop.

Comment: full_cast returns a list of 7K people with their ID but I'm afraid I can't follow what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have been able to figure this out from the documentation.

```
for person in full_cast:
    print(person['name'])
    for movie in person['filmography'].values():
        print('\t t%s %s (role: %s)' % (movie.movieID, movie['title'], movie.currentRole))
```

Comment: i thank you so very much for your help. I'm very new to Python so this isn't as intuitive as it may be for others. I ran from imdb.Person import Person


for person in full_cast:
    print(person['name'])
    for movie in person['filmography'].values():
        print('\t t%s %s (role: %s)' % (movie.movieID, movie['title'], movie.currentRole))   
And I got a Key Error: filmography